# Array length is not showing

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am using dialogflow to build a chatbot. Following is a sample question array but the format of the actual and the sample is same:

```
qstion[{
Question 1, What is 33+32?,
Okay, Question 2, What is 76+32?,
Okay, Last Question, Did you like the game? 
}]
```

I am using the following code to get the length of the array:

```
app.intent('First', (conv) => {
    const ans = conv.parameters.any;
    if(ans == 65){
            senddata[0] = qstion[0] + ans;
            conv.add(qstion.length);
            conv.ask(qstion[1]);
            }
    else{
            conv.add('Please enter a valid number');
            conv.ask(qstion[0]);
        }
});
```

The app crashes here. Can you help me get the length of the array?

Update:

This is how it shows on the log when I use console.log(qstion) :

```
qstion[
'Question1, What is 33+32',
'Okay, Question2, What is 76+32',
'Okay, Last Question, Did you like the game'
]
```

Comment: You said the app "crashes". What is the exact error that you're getting? Can you also show the exact code where `qstion` and `senddata` is defined, since your definition there doesn't look like valid code.

Comment: I have updated the question and posted here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63601907/array-length-not-showing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your question has the "dialogflow" tag I assume you are using the `actions-on-google` library. The problem you're seeing is not that your array length is wrong, but that you're using the wrong method to send a response.

In `actions-on-google`, you would call `conv.ask` or `conv.close` to ask a question or close the conversation respectively.

Your code snippet shows `conv.add(qstion.length)`. However, in the library you are using `conv.add` does not exist, likely the cause of the crash. `conv.add` only works when using the new Actions Builder and the `@assistant/conversation` library, both of which aren't compatible with Dialogflow.

Comment: So how can I get the length?

Comment: `qstion.length` is the correct way to get the length of an array.

Comment: Yeah got it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That is not a valid array, or rather a valid object in an array. I assume you meant for this to be an array of strings like

```
qstion = [
"Question 1", 
"What is 33+32?",
"Okay", 
"Question 2", 
"What is 76+32?",
"Okay", 
"Last Question", 
"Did you like the game?" 
]
```

Comment: No, These are not different, whenever I use qstion[1] I get the whole question 1

Comment: Sorry but I am not able to understand

Comment: `console.log(qstion)` try running that and see what output you get

Comment: I am updating the question on how it shows on the log